# Не могу добавить шрифты на wp

Tags: css, шрифты

Вроде делаю все как надо, но шрифт упорно не хочет ставиться

```css
@font-face {
 font-family:"Blogger Sans Light";
 src: url(/wp-content/themes/limo/css/BloggerSans-Light.ttf);
}
html, body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div, a, li{
 font-family: "Blogger Sans Light";
 list-style: none;

}
```

адрес папки точный, файл называется точно так

Comment: Здесь очень многое зависит от браузера. Особенно, когда у вас TTF шрифт. Вот здесь есть сравнительная таблица версий браузеров и форматов шрифтов: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp. Попробуйте переконвертировать в WOFF и использовать их (конвертер типа вот этого: https://everythingfonts.com/ttf-to-woff)

Comment: я проверял на всех браузерах